# How do I make a simple solid border around a FlowPane in javafx

Tags: user-interface, javafx

I'm building a simple app in javafx, and I want to be able to add a border to a FlowPane.

I have a bit more experience in java than javafx so I tried to find the equivalent of `.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(0,0,0,0))` but to no avail.

Unfortunately, everything I have found seems to be more complicated than I need. I don't need styles or dashes and that's all I'm finding.

Thanks !

Answer (score 70, accepted):

There's a `setBorder()` method, so you can add a border to your pane:

```
FlowPane pane = new FlowPane(10, 10);
pane.setBorder(new Border(new BorderStroke(Color.BLACK, 
            BorderStrokeStyle.SOLID, CornerRadii.EMPTY, BorderWidths.DEFAULT)));
```

Though this is really more simple with inline CSS:

```
pane.setStyle("-fx-border-color: black");
```

Or you could apply it with a CSS file:

```
FlowPane pane = new FlowPane(10, 10);
pane.getStyleClass().add("pane");

Scene scene = new Scene(pane, 300, 250);
scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("root.css").toExternalForm());
```

where 'root.css' is in the same package and contains:

```
.pane {
    -fx-border-color: black;
}
```

Comment: The CSS file way gives `Unknown property: "-fx-border-color"` for me, but the `setStyle()` way worked fine

Comment: @golimar Check your css file, that's a valid property for a Region, as you can see in the [CSS guide](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#region).