# Change border color on click Java

Tags: java, javafx

How to fix "Error:(94, 49) java: incompatible types: javafx.scene.paint.Color cannot be converted to javafx.scene.layout.Border"

```
    if(!tf_coPartnersDeposit.getText().matches(number))
    {
        tf_coPartnersDeposit.setBorder(Color.RED);
        System.out.println("enter number");
        return false;

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`setBorder` method takes a Border argument. You try to pass a `Color` argument which is not accepted.

So, in order to make this work, you should create a `Border` of the color you want. Something like:

```
tf_coPartnersDeposit.setBorder(new Border(new BorderStroke(Color.BLACK, 
            BorderStrokeStyle.SOLID, CornerRadii.EMPTY, BorderWidths.DEFAULT)));
```

More about JavaFX borders on this [question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27712213/how-do-i-make-a-simple-solid-border-around-a-flowpane-in-javafx)

Answer (score 0):

Use this updated code. I hope it will work for you.

```
if(!tf_coPartnersDeposit.getText().matches(number))
{
    tf_coPartnersDeposit.setStyle("-fx-border-color:red;");
    System.out.println("enter number");
    return false;

}
```